# Как узнать класс поля в gson

Tags: java, gson

Нужно узнать класс поля Gson(String, Boolean, Integer...)
Что бы в дальнейшем сравнить его с помощью instanceof.

```
gson.get("key").getClass()
```

Возвращает com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive. Но как этот примитив сравнить с классами самой java?

Answer (score 1):

Например, вот так

```
JsonElement val = gson.get("key");
if (val.isJsonPrimitive()) {
  JsonPrimitive prim = val.getAsJsonPrimitive();
  if (prim.isBoolean()) {
    boolean bool = prim.getAsBoolean();
  } else if (prim.isNumber()) {
    Number num = prim.getAsNumber();
  } else
  if (prim.isString()) {
    String str = prim.getAsString();
  }
}
```